# Does the Int type primary key insert order affect query performance in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

Table `t` has an **Int** type primary key `id` without *"Auto Increment"*

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Use the following three ways to insert data:

1. Insert sequence `id`: 1-10000
2. Descending insert `id`: 10000-1
3. Random insert `id`: 1-10000

Does the order in which rows are inserted as suggested above affect performance in `select`, `order by id` and `query` operations?

Comment: For 10K rows, it won't matter.  For a million, see Rolando's comments.  Also, MyISAM vs InnoDB matters.  And whether you have the secondary index: UNIQUE(name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already answered a question like this

- `Oct 26, 2012` : [How badly does innodb fragment in the face of somewhat out-of-order insertions?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27678/how-badly-does-innodb-fragment-in-the-face-of-somewhat-out-of-order-insertions/27685#27685)
- `Jun 28, 2012` : [Benefits of BTREE in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20047/benefits-of-btree-in-mysql/20114#20114)

Of the three methods to insert data you mentioned, I would easily choose **method #3 : Random insert id: 1-10000.** Why ?

Ascending or Descending Ordered Insertion into an index structure will generate root and node splits 45% of the time as I mentioned in my two earlier posts.

In contrast, the ordering does not matter when it comes to reloading of a table from a `mysqldump` or upon the execution of a `LOAD DATA INFILE` command. That's because of the use of sorting mechanisms after the completion of the data load of the table and the index creation can be performed.

For example, look at how a MyISAM table is reloaded.

- Data Pages for .MYD are populated
- Index Pages for .MYI are populated with unique keys in parallel with Data Page Reload
- Secondary Indexes are built by the internal execution of `Repair by sorting`

In that instance, order does not matter.

Switching gears to `SELECT ORDER BY`, performance could be nominally affected if needed keys from indexes are so split apart that multiple index pages must be accessed for ranges of data, this again leads me to choose **`method #3`**. The lower the frequency of index page splits, the fewer pages need to be read by an `ORDER BY` request.

Comment: Awesome! Insertion method #1 and #2 performance is the same?(I think it should be)

Comment: Yes, Insertion method #1 and #2 performance are the same. The only difference is that the lower values will be more fragmented in the index pages loading in ascending order, while the higher values will be more fragmented in the index pages loading in descending order.