# MySQL Slave database size >> Master Database

Tags: mysql, replication, percona

I have a Percona MySQL Master-Master setup (5.6) with second master as passive master(read-only).

Slave:

```
mysql> SELECT table_schema AS "Database", ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 2) AS "Size (MB)" FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema;
+--------------------+-----------+
| Database           | Size (MB) |
+--------------------+-----------+
| common_schema      |      1.89 |
| information_schema |      0.01 |
| mysql              |      1.70 |
| dataplay           |   1684.56 |
| dataplay1          |      0.14 |
| percona            |      0.20 |
| performance_schema |      0.00 |
+--------------------+-----------+
```

Master:

```
mysql> SELECT table_schema AS "Database", ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 2) AS "Size (MB)" FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema;
+--------------------+-----------+
| Database           | Size (MB) |
+--------------------+-----------+
| common_schema      |      1.89 |
| information_schema |      0.01 |
| mysql              |      1.69 |
| dataplay           |   1614.80 |
| dataplay1          |      0.14 |
| percona            |      0.20 |
| performance_schema |      0.00 |
+--------------------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

The size difference is massive. Is it something wrong with the setup which is running? What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

From the details, it looks like the 'massive' difference is ~70MB in the `dataplay` schema. You can adjust your query to find out exactly which tables are different.

Two potential reasons for this difference is:

- Schema difference on the master vs slave. Does the slave have utf8 instead of latin1 on a column or three? Does the slave have additional indexes? You can compare the schema by running a mysqldump of just the schema ([--no-data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data) option) and then diff'ing the results.
- The slave has actual different data. Do you have session-only data that the application stores and won't matter? If no, you can use [pt-table-checksum](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-checksum.html) to find rows that are actually different. Then you need to dig into why they are different and fix that issue before reseeding the passive master or using [pt-table-sync](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-sync.html) to resolve the differences.

Comment: Plainly, the replication setup is not proper - correct?

Comment: More likely, it is the way the applications utilize the environments is the cause of the discrepancy. Some causes can be "fixed" by updating the replication configuration, others require application changes.

Comment: @tesla747 the difference in size is not a direct proof of any problem, the database sizes will never be the same even if the actual data are.

Comment: @jkavalik correct but the size difference is way too much.. even if the master size is high and slave is less, logically it is acceptable. But this is other way around.. anyways looks like I will have to reconfigure the setup altogether

Comment: @tesla747 well, it's less than 5%, I would not call it *much*. Sounds well within the limit of a b-tree overhead imho (check answer from Rolando too). It is sure to better check if everything is ok, but other than that replication is only supposed to keep the same data, not the same storage files.

Comment: If i drop the dataplay schema in slave using super user..will the master send the dataplay schema again to sync it with slave?

Comment: @tesla747 afaik no, they do not sync, the slave only applies the same operations as the master by replaying its binlog. The schema creation won't be in new binlog so it won't be recreated.

Answer (score 2):

When you setup a Slave by loading a mysqldump from a Master, there is a strong likelihood that many of the the new Slave's tables will be bigger than the Master because of the order BTREE indexes are being loaded as the corresponding tables are being loaded. Usually that order is dictated by PRIMARY KEYs. If you talking about InnoDB, data and PRIMARY KEY nodes coexists in the same pages and segments (This is known as the [gen_clust_index or Clustered Index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html)).

This bloating of indexes due to ordered keys being loaded is also evident with MyISAM tables.

See my earlier posts

- `May 01, 2014` : [Why would the size of MySQL MyISAM table indexes (aka MYI file) not match after mysqldump import?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64230/why-would-the-size-of-mysql-myisam-table-indexes-aka-myi-file-not-match-after/64267#64267)
- `Oct 26, 2012` : [How badly does innodb fragment in the face of somewhat out-of-order insertions?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27678/how-badly-does-innodb-fragment-in-the-face-of-somewhat-out-of-order-insertions/27685#27685)

Comment: Sol Rolando..you mean to say that this is acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

Which one was built first?  How did you copy the data to the other one?  Have you ever done `OPTIMIZE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` on one machine but not the other?  ROW or STATEMENT based replication?  Same indexes?

I ask about the order of the dual-master because I would sort of expect the Master to be smaller.  RBR vs SBR impacts how the inserts/updates are performed on the Slave.  Each *secondary* index is a BTree, separate from the BTree that contains both the Data and `PRIMARY KEY`.

Anyway, if you are using InnoDB, I would not worry until the difference is more than 40%, not a mere 4%.  A BTree that has been inserted into a lot will have its blocks only about 69% full -- this is due to block splits, etc.

Comment: Master was built first. ROW based replication. No optimize runs on Master. Copied the data using Percona Xtra Backup.