# In MySQL if column X has unique values what's the difference between UNIQUE index and B-Tree index

Tags: mysql, index, unique-constraint, btree

Let's assume that I have table `data`:

```
CREATE  TABLE `test`.`data` (
`row_id` INT NOT NULL ,
`data_id` INT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`row_id`) );
```

Now, let's assume that data_id has unique values. Is there any difference(space, performance, memory) between having B-Tree index on `data_id` and UNIQUE index on it? (besides the case when InnoDB is used as storage engine and UNIQUE index can be used as clustering key so row_id is uneccesary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009577)

[image: Understanding MySQL Internals]

Page 198 says the following:

- Paragraph 6 : A MyISAM B-tree consists of leaf and nonleaf nodes, or pages.
- Paragraph 7 : Both leaf and nonleaf nodes key values and pointers to the record positions in the datafile. Nonleaf nodes additionally contains pointers to child nodes.

Given this description

- a unique index would have more nonleaf nodes. This would lend itself mode towards ordering and searching.
- nonunique index would requires less nonleaf nodes. This would lend itself mode towards doing range scans (tables and index)
- [A covering index](http://peter-zaitsev.livejournal.com/6949.html) (which would contain all needed columns for specific SELECT queries) would combine the best and worst of both. This would allow for a range scans that would need more nonleaf nodes  and provide for ordering/searching. The additional benefit would be bypassing the need for reading table data if all needed columns are present and accounted for in the index.
- I mentioned other aspects in my past post [Benefits of BTREE in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20047/benefits-of-btree-in-mysql/20114#20114)

## SPACE

- Unique Indexes would take up more space for nonleaf nodes.
- Covering indexes would need more space than a nonunqiue index but would have a higher multi-columns index cardinality that can approach the actual row count of the table.

## PERFORMANCE (Heavy-Write Environment)

- SELECTs would be very fast for exact keys
- SELECTs that only touch a Covering Index would be extremely fast
- Random INSERTs can be a nightmare due to rotations/rebalancing of nonleaf nodes
- UPDATEs that change key values can be a nightmare due to rotations/rebalancing of nonleaf nodes
- The higher the cardinality, the more nonleaf nodes, the better the performance
- The lower the cardinality, the fewer the nonleaf nodes, the worse the performance
- The more columns in the index increases the effects of the cardinality

## MEMORY

Depends on Storage Engine

- MyISAM : The key buffer only caches index pages. Covering indexs are your best friend here
- InnoDB : Buffer Pool Needs to be Big Enough to Hold Data Pages, Index Pages, and Index Page Changes (See [InnoDB Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAXdd.png), [What are the main differences between InnoDB and MyISAM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/2194#2194))